# Is it possible to process checkout and subscribe user in a single sign on?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I want to be able to capture payment and subscribe user to monthly payments at once. Is it possible using with PayPal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PayPal Subscriptions, the billing is determined by the Plan object. Separate Plans require separate checkouts. It is not possible to add them together or treat them as 'items' in a cart.

If you have multiple plans that bill on the same schedule and a user wants to subscribe to everything at the same time, you can create a new Plan with a billing_cycles -> pricing_scheme object that encompasses everything you want to bill, and use that new combined Plan for the checkout.  Alternatively you can start with a base `plan_id` and override its billing details by supplying an override `plan` object (in addition to the base `plan_id`). The override object can have a new, different billing_cycles -> pricing_scheme object which will be used instead, and also change the name of what's being subscribed to so it's not confusing.

See the documentation:

- Plans: https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create
- Subscription create: https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

If you are overriding a `plan_id` by additionally providing a `plan` with the billing_cycles->scheme, this can be done from button JavaScript where it creates the subscription. Alternatively, you can use an API to create the subscription server-side and supply that to the button JS.